# Can't reach the target page using GET request

Tags: json, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

Running my vba script I can see that it can't reach the target page where i would like to extract the different names from. Clearly I have messed somewhere up in my code but can't find out. Hope somebody will help me find out where i'm making mistakes. Thanks. Here is the code:

```
Sub Getmethod()
Dim http As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim topics, topic, ele As Object
Dim StrData As String

StrData = "what=Plumbers/where=All+States"
    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://www.yellowpages.co.za/search/" & StrData, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
    End With

    Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("resultName")
    For Each topic In topics
        Set ele = topic.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
        x = x + 1
        Cells(x, 1) = ele.innerText
    Next topic
End Sub
```

Here are the form elements:

```
<form action="/search/" class="searchForm" id="searchForm" autocomplete="off">
    <div id="whatDiv">
    <label class="searchLabel whatLabel" data-icon="">
        <input type="search" id="whatField" name="what" class="searchField whatField" placeholder="Search for companies and services" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1">
    </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="GO" class="searchBtn" tabindex="3" id="searchBtn">
    <label class="searchLabel whereLabel" data-icon="">
        <input type="search" id="whereField" name="where" class="searchField whereField" placeholder="Location" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2">
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure about the URL with search parameters? If I put this URL in browser, it doesn't return anything. When I try to search for `plumbers` in `cape town` then URL looks like this : `http://www.yellowpages.co.za/Search/plumbers/cape+town,+western+cape/1`. So maybe your URL is incorrect? Did you tryid this URL manually first?

Comment: Thanks sir dee, for your response.Nope, i didn't try it manually..

Comment: Well, then you probably should try it first in browser to see, if the URL is correct and that it actually returns something.

Comment: Checked just now n it's going to that page where i want my browser to reach. The url i tried manually is "http://www.yellowpages.co.za/search/Plumbers/All+States"

Comment: OK, so then the `StrData` is probably incorrect. It should be just `Plumbers/All+States`?

Comment: That's because I posted the form elements here to your observation whether i have made any mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the content of `StrData` to `"Plumbers/All+States"`. Then the data are returned like this:

```
Flinkdink Plumbers CC →
AD-Hoc Plumbers →
GANGA PLUMBERS →
BURGESS PLUMBING →
Burgess & Partners →
Drainmen →
Drainmen →
Anchor Electrical →
Cobra →
Bryanston Plumbing (Pty) Ltd →
Amazon →
A A A Plumbers →
A A A Plumbing →
A A A Plumbing →
Berea Plumbers →
Drain Blasters →
R C Bosman Plumbing →
R C Bosman Plumbing →
Currie Plumbers →
DRAIN GEYSER PLUMBING EXPERTS →
```

Comment: Changed the parameter in my post to satisfy the requirement of StrData but still no luck.

Comment: What does 'no luck' mean exactly? Do you get some error or do you not get expected data?

Comment: I get nothing. No error either. When debugged I could see that after hitting [For Each topic In topics]  it gets to the end sub line.

Comment: So the Url you are using now look like this `http://www.yellowpages.co.za/search/Plumbers/All+States` right? When you put this Url to browser like Internet Explorer and press Enter then the server returns results so you can see them in the browser, right? But when you use this Url in VBA code, it returns no results, do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes sir, this is it. I was not around my pc so got delayed to respond.

Comment: Did you tried e.g. .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html` and `Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5`?

Comment: Tried just now with both the request headers. Still the same. No result, no error.

Comment: `Debug.Print .Status & ", " & .statusText` this prints `200, OK`?

Comment: So you will probably need something like `fidler` so you can analyze and compare the requests sent by the browser and VBA code and try to find the difference(s) which prevents the server to send the data. I can't help here :(.

Comment: Hi sir dee, i thought in the first place that it is happening because the requested data is in json format.

Comment: You get json from server? If so then dont parse it as html, but as json.

Comment: If you instruct me properly in the first place that the StrData parameter should be what you answered in your very first attempt without using (what and where) then we did not have to think so deep. Anyways, thanks for your effective solution.